# Parse PHP array in ASP.NET web service?

Tags: php, asp.net, arrays, web-services, parsing

For a web service having this structure in PHP:

```
function getAlbums($quantity) 
    {

       /* this is a sample array */

        $albums=array();
        $albums[0]['title']='Stripped';
        $albums[0]['artist']='Christina Aguilera';
        $albums[0]['genre']='Pop';
        $albums[0]['songs'][0]='Beautiful';
        $albums[0]['songs'][1]='Fighter';

        $return=array();
        for($i=0;$i<=$quantity;$i++){

           $return[$i]=$albums[$i]; 

        }

        return $return;

    }
```

I have it displaying fine in my browser with a PHP client, but now how do I parse it in ASP.NET to show the data?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean you are using a PHP service that outputs data as PHP array and you want to display that array in your ASP.net based site? If so, read my asnwer below. If you meant something else, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things are completely opposite: they both are different language. You need something inn the middle between them. Preferably a database, at worse some kind of file system...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why/how you are clubbing PHP and ASP.net. But when you want to exchange data between two different systems you can convert it into an intermediate format that both understands. In any such situation you can convert your data into JSON and read that data from ASP.net. By doing this, you can convert your PHP array into an array ASp.net. Hope this helps...

Comment: I have a Publisher service that gets all the new albums in PHP and what my ASP.NET should do is get those albums and insert them in its own database. So, I should simply return JSON having the created array?

Comment: If you have control over the PHP's output, convert the array into json using json_encode($arr) and print it. In ASP you can decode that json and that will give you the same array in ASP.net. No idea about function to decode json but there are in-built json functions available in asp.net for sure.